# Is a spanning tree *minimal* if any cycle resulting from adding an edge $e$ contains no edges with weight greater than $w(e)$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $T$ be a spanning tree on some graph $G$. Adding any edge $e$ from $G$ to $T$ would result in a cycle. Consider the following two statements:

1. $T$ is a minimum spanning tree on $G$.
2. The cycle resulting from adding any $e$ from $G$ to $T$ will not have any edges with weight greater than $e$.

It is easy to see that 1 implies 2, since if 2 were false, then you could add $e$ in and remove the edge with higher weight, resulting in a tree with lower weight than $T$, a contradiction.

**However, does 2 imply 1?** I'm guessing yes, though it's unclear to me how to prove the impossibility of "locally minimum" spanning trees, for which 2 is true but the tree is still not a global minimum.

There's a theorem that's somewhat related, but I'm not sure how to apply it to this question:

> if $G$ has some cycle $c$, then
> there exists some MST of G that does not include the edge $e'$ with the
> largest weight on that cycle $c$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes: the spanning tree *is* guaranteed to be minimum.

The following proof paraphrases [another answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/57486/82288).

Define a "local MST" $T$ as a spanning tree with property 2 in the question. Let $w(T)$ be the total weight of all edges in tree $T$.

**Lemma**: For any two local MSTs $T$ and $T'$, we have $w(T)$ = $w(T')$.

**Proof**:

If $T$ and $T'$ have the same edges, then we are done.

Otherwise, consider the set $S$ of edges that are in exactly one of $T$ and $T'$. Clearly $|S|$ must be even. Let $e$ be an edge with minimal weight in $S$, and without loss of generality let $e \in T$.

Adding $e$ to $T'$ would create a cycle, and that cycle must contain at least one other edge $e'$ in $S$, since $e$ existed in $T$ without causing a cycle.

By definition of $e$, we have $w(e) \leq w(e')$, but since $T'$ is a local MST, we have $w(e) \geq w(e')$, and thus $w(e) = w(e')$.

Thus, replacing $e'$ with $e$ in $T'$ keeps $w(T')$ invariant and removes both $e$ and $e'$ from $S$. Repeat the above until $S$ is empty and thus $T = T'$. Since $w(T')$ stayed constant the entire time, we must have had $w(T) = w(T')$ in the very beginning, QED.

**Main result**: A local MST is a true "global" minimum spanning tree.

**Proof**:

As discussed in the question, property 1 implies property 2 and thus an MST is a local MST. From the lemma, all local MSTs have the same weight, and thus the result follows.